# How do you find the IQR in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a baked-in Numpy/Scipy function to find the interquartile range?  I can do it pretty easily myself, but `mean()` exists which is basically `sum/len`...

```
def IQR(dist):
    return np.percentile(dist, 75) - np.percentile(dist, 25)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a function for it, you must compute the percentiles as you did.

Comment: @BrenBarn. There is now...

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`np.percentile` takes multiple percentile arguments, and you are slightly better off doing:

```
q75, q25 = np.percentile(x, [75 ,25])
iqr = q75 - q25
```

or

```
iqr = np.subtract(*np.percentile(x, [75, 25]))
```

than making two calls to `percentile`:

```
In [8]: x = np.random.rand(1e6)

In [9]: %timeit q75, q25 = np.percentile(x, [75 ,25]); iqr = q75 - q25
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit iqr = np.subtract(*np.percentile(x, [75, 25]))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit iqr = np.percentile(x, 75) - np.percentile(x, 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Using the ufunc machinery, `np.substract.reduce`. IMHO, a tad clearer than the * magic.

Comment: @Jaime
what is the * operator? what is it doing?

Comment: It's unpacking the tuple after it, so that instead of a two item sequence, the function is passed two individual items.

Comment: Subtracting two numbers is O(1) while finding %iles takes O(n), so unpacking the two things and very explicitly adding them is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 32):

There is now an [`iqr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html) function in `scipy.stats`. It is available as of scipy 0.18.0. My original intent was to add it to numpy, but it was considered too domain-specific.

You may be better off just using Jaime's answer, since the scipy code is just an over-complicated version of the same.

Comment: Why would IQR be considered too domain-specific for numpy?

Comment: Because it is not a widely used metric. Feel free to search the mailing list for details.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore this if [Jaime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23229224/5609823) works for your case. But if not, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551756/5609823), to find the *exact* values of 1st and 3rd quartiles, you should consider doing something like:

```
samples = sorted([28, 12, 8, 27, 16, 31, 14, 13, 19, 1, 1, 22, 13])

def find_median(sorted_list):
    indices = []

    list_size = len(sorted_list)
    median = 0

    if list_size % 2 == 0:
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2) - 1)  # -1 because index starts from 0
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2))

        median = (sorted_list[indices[0]] + sorted_list[indices[1]]) / 2
        pass
    else:
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2))

        median = sorted_list[indices[0]]
        pass

    return median, indices
    pass

median, median_indices = find_median(samples)
Q1, Q1_indices = find_median(samples[:median_indices[0]])
Q2, Q2_indices = find_median(samples[median_indices[-1] + 1:])

IQR = Q3 - Q1

quartiles = [Q1, median, Q2]
```

Code taken from the referenced answer.