# How to calculate 1st and 3rd quartiles?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have DataFrame:

```
    time_diff   avg_trips
0   0.450000    1.0
1   0.483333    1.0
2   0.500000    1.0
3   0.516667    1.0
4   0.533333    2.0
```

I want to get 1st quartile, 3rd quartile and median for the column `time_diff`. To obtain median, I use `np.median(df["time_diff"].values)`.

How can I calculate quartiles?

Comment: hope the link will help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

Comment: Are you also looking for the IQR? You'll want `pd.qcut` instead.

Comment: what is df? I get this type of error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time_diff'`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

By using `pandas`:

```
df.time_diff.quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])


Out[793]: 
0.25    0.483333
0.50    0.500000
0.75    0.516667
Name: time_diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: bear in mind that there are 15 different ways to calculate quartiles.. so look under the hood as different functions may give slightly different results (pandas vs numpy vs scipy..) http://jse.amstat.org/v14n3/langford.html

Comment: Yup, I used to use `df.quantile(q=[0.25, 0.75], axis=0, numeric_only=True, interpolation='midpoint')` -- this calculates Q1 and Q3 for the dataframe (each series separately)

Comment: @ahmedhosny thanks for sharing the paper. Figured out how it maps onto Python. For [pandas interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) and for [numpy method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy.percentile)  needs to be specified. Scipy stats only seems to have the [IQR](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) function.

Comment: what is df? import statements? what is this?

Comment: error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time_diff'`

Comment: @CharlieParker data show in the question

Answer (score 89):

You can use [`np.percentile`](https://web.archive.org/web/20161014035550/http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to calculate quartiles (including the median):

```
>>> np.percentile(df.time_diff, 25)  # Q1
0.48333300000000001

>>> np.percentile(df.time_diff, 50)  # median
0.5

>>> np.percentile(df.time_diff, 75)  # Q3
0.51666699999999999
```

Or all at once:

```
>>> np.percentile(df.time_diff, [25, 50, 75])
array([ 0.483333,  0.5     ,  0.516667])
```

Comment: Or np.nanpercentile,  if you have NaNs in your dataset

Answer (score 29):

Coincidentally, this information is captured with the `describe` method:

```
df.time_diff.describe()

count    5.000000
mean     0.496667
std      0.032059
min      0.450000
25%      0.483333
50%      0.500000
75%      0.516667
max      0.533333
Name: time_diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How would one call the 25% and the mean into `vars` `my_mean` and `my_firstquartile`?

Comment: `my_mean = df.time_diff.describe()[1]`
`my_firstquartile = df.time_diff.describe()[4]`

Comment: what is df? I get `error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time_diff'``

Comment: @CharlieParker just call describe() on your DataFrame/Series. time_diff is the name of a column in the example df provided by the OP. Your DataFrame doesn't have it. Just choose the column(s) you want from your df.

Answer (score 27):

[`np.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) **DOES NOT** calculate the values of Q1, median, and Q3. Consider the sorted list below:

```
samples = [1, 1, 8, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 19, 22, 27, 28, 31]
```

running `np.percentile(samples, [25, 50, 75])` returns the actual values from the list:

```
Out[1]: array([12., 14., 22.])
```

However, the quartiles are `Q1=10.0, Median=14, Q3=24.5` (you can also use this [link](https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/quartile-q1-q3) to find the quartiles and median online).
One can use the below code to calculate the quartiles and median of a sorted list (because of sorting this approach requires `O(nlogn)` computations where `n` is the number of items).
Moreover, finding quartiles and median can be done in `O(n)` computations using the [Median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) Selection algorithm ([order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)).

```
samples = sorted([28, 12, 8, 27, 16, 31, 14, 13, 19, 1, 1, 22, 13])

def find_median(sorted_list):
    indices = []

    list_size = len(sorted_list)
    median = 0

    if list_size % 2 == 0:
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2) - 1)  # -1 because index starts from 0
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2))

        median = (sorted_list[indices[0]] + sorted_list[indices[1]]) / 2
        pass
    else:
        indices.append(int(list_size / 2))

        median = sorted_list[indices[0]]
        pass

    return median, indices
    pass

median, median_indices = find_median(samples)
Q1, Q1_indices = find_median(samples[:median_indices[0]])
Q3, Q3_indices = find_median(samples[median_indices[-1] + 1:])

quartiles = [Q1, median, Q3]

print("(Q1, median, Q3): {}".format(quartiles))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I spent at least one hour trying to understand why `describe` wasn't outputting the precise quartile value, until I thought that the 25th percentile isn't exactly equals to Q1. Well done!

Comment: @Wladston if duplicated value in sample, which will yield the different result

Comment: There is no single definition of the percentile, so this is a situation where nearly everyone got the correct answer.

Comment: `np.percentile` does just what it does... if you are used to the "definition" with midpoint... just check your link of the doc of numpy to see the right signature

Answer (score 15):

Building upon or rather correcting a bit on what Babak said....

[np.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) **DOES VERY MUCH** calculate the values of Q1, median, and Q3. Consider the sorted list below:

```
s1=[18,45,66,70,76,83,88,90,90,95,95,98]
```

running `np.percentile(s1, [25, 50, 75])` returns the actual values from the list:

```
[69.  85.5  91.25]
```

However, the quartiles are Q1=68.0, Median=85.5, Q3=92.5, which is the **correct** thing to say

What we are missing here is the **interpolation** parameter of the `np.percentile` and related functions. By default the value of this argument is **linear**. This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use when the desired quantile lies between two data points i < j:
linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.
lower: i.
higher: j.
nearest: i or j, whichever is nearest.
midpoint: (i + j) / 2.

Thus running `np.percentile(s1, [25, 50, 75], interpolation='midpoint')` returns the actual results for the list:

```
[68. 85.5 92.5]
```

Comment: This does **NOT** work for same list of values that Cyrus used, 'midpoint' is the result as 'linear' for his list. Your solution works because you have an even number of values. Cyrus has an odd number of values, if you add an additional value is this still giving you the result you expect?

Comment: from `numpy` >= 1.22 `interpolation`  is deprecated, use `method` instead. See my answer for details

Answer (score 7):

Using `np.percentile`.

```
q75, q25 = np.percentile(DataFrame, [75,25])
iqr = q75 - q25
```

Answer from [How do you find the IQR in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228244/how-do-you-find-the-iqr-in-numpy)

Comment: q25 and q75 are medians of first and second half respectively , If I want mean of first half and mean of second half ?

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
df.describe()
```

which would show the information

[image: df.describe()]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use raw python rather than numpy or panda, you can use the python stats module to find the median of  the upper and lower half of the list:

```
    >>> import statistics as stat
    >>> def quartile(data):
            data.sort()               
            half_list = int(len(data)//2)
            upper_quartile = stat.median(data[-half_list:])
            lower_quartile = stat.median(data[:half_list])
            print("Lower Quartile: "+str(lower_quartile))
            print("Upper Quartile: "+str(upper_quartile))
            print("Interquartile Range: "+str(upper_quartile-lower_quartile)
    
    >>> quartile(df.time_diff)
```

Line 1: import the statistics module under the alias "stat"

Line 2: define the quartile function

Line 3: sort the data into ascending order

Line 4: get the length of half of the list

Line 5: get the median of the lower half of the list

Line 6: get the median of the upper half of the list

Line 7: print the lower quartile

Line 8: print the upper quartile

Line 9: print the interquartile range

Line 10: run the quartile function for the time_diff column of the DataFrame

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution with no external library. Just to note you have a typo `upper_quartile = stat.median(data[-half_list:])` (needs colon to define as slice)

Answer (score 2):

In my efforts to learn object-oriented programming alongside learning statistics, I made this, maybe you'll find it useful:

```
samplesCourse = [9, 10, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 19, 21, 23, 28, 30, 33, 34, 36, 44, 45, 47, 60]

class sampleSet:
    def __init__(self, sampleList):
        self.sampleList = sampleList
        self.interList = list(sampleList) # interList is sampleList alias; alias used to maintain integrity of original sampleList

    def find_median(self):
        self.median = 0

        if len(self.sampleList) % 2 == 0:
            # find median for even-numbered sample list length
            self.medL = self.interList[int(len(self.interList)/2)-1]
            self.medU = self.interList[int(len(self.interList)/2)]
            self.median = (self.medL + self.medU)/2

        else:
            # find median for odd-numbered sample list length
            self.median = self.interList[int((len(self.interList)-1)/2)]
        return self.median

    def find_1stQuartile(self, median):
        self.lower50List = []
        self.Q1 = 0

        # break out lower 50 percentile from sampleList
        if len(self.interList) % 2 == 0:
            self.lower50List = self.interList[:int(len(self.interList)/2)]
        else:
            # drop median to make list ready to divide into 50 percentiles
            self.interList.pop(interList.index(self.median))
            self.lower50List = self.interList[:int(len(self.interList)/2)]

        # find 1st quartile (median of lower 50 percentiles)
        if len(self.lower50List) % 2 == 0:
            self.Q1L = self.lower50List[int(len(self.lower50List)/2)-1]
            self.Q1U = self.lower50List[int(len(self.lower50List)/2)]
            self.Q1 = (self.Q1L + self.Q1U)/2

        else:
            self.Q1 = self.lower50List[int((len(self.lower50List)-1)/2)]

        return self.Q1

    def find_3rdQuartile(self, median):
        self.upper50List = []
        self.Q3 = 0

        # break out upper 50 percentile from sampleList
        if len(self.sampleList) % 2 == 0:
            self.upper50List = self.interList[int(len(self.interList)/2):]
        else:
            self.interList.pop(interList.index(self.median))
            self.upper50List = self.interList[int(len(self.interList)/2):]

        # find 3rd quartile (median of upper 50 percentiles)
        if len(self.upper50List) % 2 == 0:
            self.Q3L = self.upper50List[int(len(self.upper50List)/2)-1]
            self.Q3U = self.upper50List[int(len(self.upper50List)/2)]
            self.Q3 = (self.Q3L + self.Q3U)/2

        else:
            self.Q3 = self.upper50List[int((len(self.upper50List)-1)/2)]

        return self.Q3

    def find_InterQuartileRange(self, Q1, Q3):
        self.IQR = self.Q3 - self.Q1
        return self.IQR

    def find_UpperFence(self, Q3, IQR):
        self.fence = self.Q3 + 1.5 * self.IQR
        return self.fence

samples = sampleSet(samplesCourse)
median = samples.find_median()
firstQ = samples.find_1stQuartile(median)
thirdQ = samples.find_3rdQuartile(median)
iqr = samples.find_InterQuartileRange(firstQ, thirdQ)
fence = samples.find_UpperFence(thirdQ, iqr)

print("Median is: ", median)
print("1st quartile is: ", firstQ)
print("3rd quartile is: ", thirdQ)
print("IQR is: ", iqr)
print("Upper fence is: ", fence)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main difference of the signatures between [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)
and [pandas.quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html): with `pandas` the `q` paramter should be given in a scala between [0-1] instead with `numpy` between [0-100].

Both of them, by default, use a `linear` interpolation technique to find such quantities. Instead, [`DataFrame.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) has a less flexible signature and allow to use *only* the `linear` one.

In `numpy` >= 1.22 the parameter `interpolation` is deprecated and replaced with `method`.

Here an example of usage with *linear interpolation*: (default behavior)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


s =[18,45,66,70,76,83,88,90,90,95,95,98, 100]
print(pd.DataFrame(s).quantile(q=[.25, .50, .75]))
print(np.percentile(s, q=[25, 50, 75]))
print(pd.DataFrame(s).describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75])) # the parameter is redundant, it's the default behavior
```

Here using the *midpoint* interpolation:

```
s_even = [18,45,66,70,76,83,88,90,90,95,95,98]
print(pd.DataFrame(s_even).quantile(q=[.25, .5, .75], interpolation='midpoint'))
print(np.percentile(s_even, q=[25, 50, 75], interpolation='midpoint')) # verion < 1.22
print(np.percentile(s_even, q=[25, 50, 75], method='midpoint')) # version >= 1.22

s_odd = s_even + [100] # made it odd
print(pd.DataFrame(s_odd).quantile(q=[.25, .50, .75], interpolation='midpoint'))
print(np.percentile(s_odd, q=[25, 50, 75], interpolation='midpoint')) # verion < 1.22
print(np.percentile(s_odd, q=[25, 50, 75], method='midpoint')) # version >= 1.22
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using the python statistics module.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

```
import statistics

time_diff = [0.45,0.483333,0.5,0.516667,0.5333333]
statistics.quantiles(time_diff, method='inclusive')
```

[0.483333, 0.5, 0.516667]

The above defaults to 4 groups of data (n=4) with 3 split points (1st quartile, median, 3rd quartile), and setting the method to inclusive uses all the data in the list.
The output is a list of 1st quartile, median and 3rd quartile.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem when trying to find a package that finds quartiles. That's not to say the others are wrong but to say this is how I personally would have defined quartiles. It is similar to Shikar's results with using mid-point but also works on lists that have an odd length. If the quartile position is between lengths, it will use the average of the neighbouring values. (i.e. position always treated as either the exact position or 0.5 of the position)

```
import math

def find_quartile_postions(size):
    if size == 1:
        # All quartiles are the first (only) element
        return 0, 0, 0
    elif size == 2:
        # Lower quartile is first element, Upper quartile is second element, Median is average
        # Set to 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 if you prefer all quartiles to be the mean value
        return 0, 0.5, 1
    else:
        # Lower quartile is element at 1/4th position, median at 1/2th, upper at 3/4
        # Quartiles can be between positions if size + 1 is not divisible by 4
        return (size + 1) / 4 - 1, (size + 1) / 2 - 1, 3 * (size + 1) / 4 - 1

def find_quartiles(num_array):
    size = len(num_array)
    
    if size == 0:
        quartiles = [0,0,0]
    else:
        sorted_array = sorted(num_array)
        lower_pos, median_pos, upper_pos = find_quartile_postions(size)

        # Floor so can work in arrays
        floored_lower_pos = math.floor(lower_pos)
        floored_median_pos = math.floor(median_pos)
        floored_upper_pos = math.floor(upper_pos)

        # If position is an integer, the quartile is the elem at position
        # else the quartile is the mean of the elem & the elem one position above
        lower_quartile = (sorted_array[floored_lower_pos]
                          if (lower_pos % 1 == 0)
                          else (sorted_array[floored_lower_pos] + sorted_array[floored_lower_pos + 1]) / 2
                         )

        median = (sorted_array[floored_median_pos]
                          if (median_pos % 1 == 0)
                          else (sorted_array[floored_median_pos] + sorted_array[floored_median_pos + 1]) / 2
                         )

        upper_quartile = (sorted_array[floored_upper_pos]
                          if (upper_pos % 1 == 0)
                          else (sorted_array[floored_upper_pos] + sorted_array[floored_upper_pos + 1]) / 2
                         )

        quartiles = [lower_quartile, median, upper_quartile]

    return quartiles
```

Answer (score 0):

try that way:

```
dfo = sorted(df.time_diff)

n=len(dfo)

Q1=int((n+3)/4)  
Q3=int((3*n+1)/4)  


print("Q1 position: ", Q1, "Q1 position: " ,Q3)

print("Q1 value: ", dfo[Q1], "Q1 value: ", dfo[Q3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in using JS, I have developed a solution:

```
var
withThis = (obj, cb) => cb(obj),
sort = array => array.sort((a, b) => a - b),

fractile = (array, parts, nth) => withThis(
  (nth * (array.length + 1) / parts),
  decimal => withThis(Math.floor(decimal),
    even => withThis(sort(array),
      sorted => sorted[even - 1] + (
        (decimal - even) * (
          sorted[even] - sorted[even - 1]
        )
      )
    )
  )
),

data = [
  78, 72, 74, 79, 74, 71, 75, 74, 72, 68,
  72, 73, 72, 74, 75, 74, 73, 74, 65, 72,
  66, 75, 80, 69, 82, 73, 74, 72, 79, 71,
  70, 75, 71, 70, 70, 70, 75, 76, 77, 67
]

fractile(data, 4, 1) // 1st Quartile is 71
fractile(data, 10, 3) // 3rd Decile is 71.3
fractile(data, 100, 82) // 82nd Percentile is 75.62
```

You can just copy paste the codes onto your browser and get the exact result.
And more about 'Statistics with JS' can be found in https://gist.github.com/rikyperdana/a7349c790cf5b034a1b77db64415e73c/edit

Answer (score 0):

Full working example:

```
import numpy as np
sizes_height = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(sizes_height)
# df = pd.Series(sizes_height)
# x = df.time_diff.quantile(sizes_height)
x = df.describe()
print()
x
                0
count  100.000000
mean     0.059808
std      1.012960
min     -2.552990
25%     -0.643857
50%      0.094096
75%      0.737077
max      2.269755
```