# Different results when calculating quantile in pandas (Python) and R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas

Could you please tell me, why the  results differ, when quantiles are calculated in pandas (Python) and R?

Pandas code:

```
 print('p_new:   {:>5}   {:>5}     {:>5}'.format(
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['pending_new'].quantile(0.50), 2),
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['pending_new'].quantile(0.95), 2),
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['pending_new'].quantile(0.99), 2),
    ))

    print('new:     {:>5}   {:>5}   {:>5}'.format(
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['new'].quantile(0.50), 2),
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['new'].quantile(0.95), 2),
        round(self.pandas_data_frame['new'].quantile(0.99), 2),
    ))
```

results:

```
name     |   .50|    .95|    .99| 
p_new:     2.0    12.0      20.0
new:      52.0    78.0   106.06
```

R code:

```
dd = read.csv(“stats.csv”)
quantile(dd$pending_new, c(.50, .95, .99))
quantile(dd$new, c(.50, .95, .99))
```

results:

```
> quantile(dd$pending_new, c(.50, .95, .99))                                                                                                                                               
50%  95%  99% 
2.0 13.1 34.0 
> quantile(dd$new, c(.50, .95, .99))                                                                                                                                                       
50%    95%    99% 
52.00  81.00 129.26
```

Comment: Use the sources ([pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) and [r](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html)), Luke!

Comment: There are many different [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) to estimate quantiles. R uses one way by default, pandas uses another.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this function in Python, all functions of the `np.percentile()` family have an optional argument interpolation. Set this argument to 'midpoint' and your results with match the result in R.
You can also read more about the python function here:
[How to calculate 1st and 3rd quartiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926230/how-to-calculate-1st-and-3rd-quartiles/57784105#57784105)