# Inaccuracy in calculating quartiles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quartile

I'm trying to calculate quartiles of my column. However any kind of functions i used (So far, i tried with numpy percentile and pandas quantile with interpolation nearest,higher,lower,linear) they always return inaccurate quartile. I checked it from this link [here](https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/quartile-q1-q3). Is there any function that could really return accurate quartiles or it is probably better to make our own function to accurately count it? Because i have seen in another answer someone created their own function to count it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926230/how-to-calculate-1st-and-3rd-quartiles/45926291)

This is my column, the result suppossed to be `Q1,Q3 = 200,650` but what shows is `Q1,Q3 = 200,500`. Whatever the interpolation i used, there's always inacurrate result.

```
cols = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[100,300,200,400,500,6000,800,200,200]})
```

Answer (score 3):

After we drop the duplicate, when you do not drop the duplicate the value will be off with `quantile`

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[100,300,200,400,500,6000,800,200,200]})
s.drop_duplicates().quantile([0.25,0.75])
Out[13]: 
      numbers
0.25    250.0
0.75    650.0
```

Comment: but the Q1 supposed to be 200