# Is scipy.stats doing wrong calculation for iqr?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i am coding on a dataset [23,25,28,28,32,33,35]

according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) and [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html)

IQR = Q3 − Q1 = 33 - 25 = 8

when I run IQR on a dataset, the result (6) is not as expected (8).

I tried another method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23229224, and the result is 6.

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import iqr
x = np.array([23,25,28,28,32,33,35])
print(iqr(x, axis=0))
```

what leads to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scipy.stats.iqr` doesn't seem to follow the recursive algorithm documented in Wikipedia.  Instead it simply does `np.percentile(x, 75) - np.percentile(x, 25)`  This is not exclusive of the median, it is inclusive, so you get `(32 + 33)/2 - (25 + 28)/2 = 6`

If you want to use the algorithm in wikipedia you'd need to do something like:

```
def iqr_(m):
    m = np.array(m)
    n = m.size//2
    m_ = np.partition(m.ravel(), n + 1)
    return np.median(m_[n + m.size%2:]) - np.median(m_[:n])

iqr_([23,25,28,28,32,33,35])
8.0
```

EDIT: On the [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Interquartile_range) of wikipedia it is brought up that the algorithm presented is not definitive, and in fact the method of `scipy.stats.iqr` is also acceptable.  See the three methods for determining quartiles [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile)

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is amazing. For me, if the length of data is even, I will use `stats.iqr`, like

```
d = [21, 23,25,28,28,32,33,35]
# Check the length of the dataset
>>> len(d)
8
>>> Q1 = np.percentile(d, 25,interpolation='midpoint')
>>> Q3 = np.percentile(d, 75,interpolation='midpoint')
>>> Q3-Q1
8.5
# When use stats.iqr
>>> stats.iqr(d, interpolation='midpoint')
8.5
```

Thus, the even length of dataset can directly use stats.iqr. The odd number of dataset, we might use Daniel's method, Cuz `stats.iqr` is not exclusive of the median, it is inclusive.