# Incorrect first quantile and third quantile value over array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, quantile

I need help in understanding how the quantile function works in `numpy`. because the answers do not match with other quantile calculators.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] 

print("arr : ", arr)  
print("Q2 quantile of arr : ", np.quantile(arr, .50)) 
print("Q1 quantile of arr : ", np.quantile(arr, .25)) 
print("Q3 quantile of arr : ", np.quantile(arr, .75))
```

I expected the output of Q1 to be 1.5 and Q3 to be 4.5 
I verified it using an [online calculator](http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/quartiles/). It also differs from the answer given by numpy . 
Can someone help me in understanding how numpy calculates quantile and why is it different from the actual formula .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is scipy.stats doing wrong calculation for iqr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943661/is-scipy-stats-doing-wrong-calculation-for-iqr)

Comment: There is no difinitive method for calculating quartiles in literature.  `numpy` does `precentile(arr, 25)`, which is an approved method, but many others methods split the array twice, which removes the median when the array has an odd number of values.

Answer (score 1):

For some ungodly reason statistics as a discipline hasn't defined exactly what a quartile is, despite using it in many "standard" formulas.  [Here's three different methods of calculating it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) which which are all very different.  Luckily when datasets are large the differences are small, but with only five values . . . well, you can get some very big differences.

- Your online calculator uses method 1 and returns `[1.5, 4.5]`.
- The answer with method 2 would be `[2, 4]`
- `numpy` uses method 3 and returns `[2, 4]`

It seems to me like methods 2 and 3 would always give the same answer but there may be differences I haven't seen.

Comment: I dont think i am getting [2,4] as an answer using method 3 . there are 5 elements so n=1 . 25% of 1st data value = 0.25 . 75% of the 2nd (n+1) data value = 1.5 . so Q1 = 1.75

Comment: Also using the 1st example given in the wikipedia link the answers are different .according to numpy 
Q2 quantile of arr :  40.0
Q1 quantile of arr :  25.5
Q3 quantile of arr :  42.5