# Using Numpy, how 25 percentile is calculate for number 1 to10?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile, quartile, iqr

```
from numpy import percentile
import numpy as np
data=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
# calculate quartiles
quartile_1 = percentile(data, 25)
quartile_3 =percentile(data, 75)
# calculate min/max

print(quartile_1) # show 3.25
print(quartile_3) # shows 7.75
```

can you explain how 3.25 and 7.75 value are calculated? I expected them to be 3 and 8.

Comment: `percentile(..., interpolation='nearest')`, see [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Comment: If you're expecting *exactly* `[3,8]`, `numpy` does not use an iterative median method to determine quartiles, it *always* uses interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

Step-by-step calculation of Numpy percentile manually:

**Step-1**: Find length

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
l = len(x) 
# Output --> 10
```

**Step-2**: Subtract `1` to get distance from first to last item in `x`

```
# n = (length - 1) 
# n = (10-1) 
# Output --> 9
```

**Step-3**: Multiply `n` by quantile, here 25th percentile or 0.25 quantile or 1st quartile

```
n * 0.25
# Therefore, (9 * 0.25) 
# Output --> 2.25
# So, fraction is 0.25 part of 2.25
# m = 0.25
```

**Step-4**: Now get final answer

**For Linear:**

```
# i + (j - i) * m
# Here, think i and j as values at indices
# x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#idx= [0,1,2,3,.........,9]
# So, for '2.25':
# value at index immediately before 2.25, is at index=2 so, i=3
# value at index immediately after 2.25, is at index=3 so, i=4
# and fractions 
3 + (4 - 3)*0.25
# Output --> 3.25
```

**For Lower**:

```
# Here, based on output from Step-3
# Because, it is '2.25', 
# Find a number a index lower than 2.25
# So, lower index is '2'
# x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#idx= [0,1,2,3,.........,9]
# So, at index=2 we have '3' 
# Output --> 3
```

**For Higher**:

```
# Here, based on output from Step-3
# Because, it is '2.25', 
# Find a number a index higher than 2.25
# So, higher index is '3'
# x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#idx= [0,1,2,3,.........,9]
# So, at index=3 we have '4' 
# Output --> 4
```

**For Nearest**:

```
# Here, based on output from Step-3
# Because, it is '2.25', 
# Find a number a index nearest to 2.25
# So, nearest index is '2'
# x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#idx= [0,1,2,3,.........,9]
# So, at index=2 we have '3' 
# Output --> 3
```

**For Midpoint**:

```
# Here, based on output from Step-3
# (i + j)/2
# Here, think i and j as values at indices
# x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#idx= [0,1,2,3,.........,9]
# So, for '2.25'
# value at index immediately before 2.25, is at index=2 so, i=3
# value at index immediately after 2.25, is at index=3 so, i=4
(3+4)/2
# Output --> 3.5
```

Code in Python:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print("linear:", np.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='linear'))
print("lower:", np.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='lower'))
print("higher:", np.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='higher'))
print("nearest:", np.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='nearest'))
print("midpoint:", np.percentile(x, 25, interpolation='midpoint'))
```

Output:

```
linear: 3.25
lower: 3
higher: 4
nearest: 3
midpoint: 3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Versions 1.9.0 of Numpy or greater have an optional 'interpolation' parameter, which is linear by default.

> This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use when the desired percentile lies between two data points i < j:
>
> ‘linear’: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

If you're looking to change that behavior, you'll just want to add the argument manually and override the default using `interpolation='nearest’`

Answer (score 1):

While this could be an interpolation issue, by some [quartile methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) (namely method 2) the answer should be *exactly* `[3, 8]`

As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943661/is-scipy-stats-doing-wrong-calculation-for-iqr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212996/incorrect-first-quantile-and-third-quantile-value-over-array-using-numpy/57214262#57214262), `numpy` uses method 3 instead.

Unfortunately until the field of statistics comes up with a unified definition of what a quartile is, confusion will continue.

Answer (score 0):

From `numpy` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

> Given a vector V of length N, the q-th percentile of V is the value
>   q/100 of the way from the minimum to the maximum in a sorted copy of
>   V. The values and distances of the two nearest neighbors as well as
>   the interpolation parameter will determine the percentile if the
>   normalized ranking does not match the location of q exactly. This
>   function is the same as the median if q=50, the same as the minimum if
>   q=0 and the same as the maximum if q=100.

So the issue is with how numpy reacts when an exact match to your quantile is not found. If you use `interpolation="nearest"`, you will get the results you would expect to get:

```
>>> from numpy import percentile
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> # calculate quartiles
... quartile_1 = percentile(data, 25, interpolation="nearest")
>>> quartile_3 = percentile(data, 75, interpolation="nearest")
>>> print(quartile_1) 
3
>>> print(quartile_3) 
8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various options that can be used depending on the type of interpolation method that you want the percentile to be calculated at.

```
a = np.arange(1, 11)
a  # array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='midpoint') # array([3.5, 7.5])
np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='nearest')  # array([3, 8])
np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='nearest')  # array([3, 8])
np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='linear')   # array([3.25, 7.75])
np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='lower')    # array([3, 7])
np.percentile(a, (25, 75), interpolation='higher')   # array([4, 8])
```

You will note that the cumulative relative frequency is what the percentiles need to be derived from

```
c = np.cumsum(a)
c  # ---- array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55], dtype=int32)
c/c[-1] * 100
array([  1.81818182,   5.45454545,  10.90909091,  18.18181818,
        27.27272727,  38.18181818,  50.90909091,  65.45454545,
        81.81818182, 100.        ])
```

and percentiles for 25 and 75 will require an interpolation of some form.